# Azure Bot Framework Web Chat in Nodejs: Not able to recognize prompts while converting text to speech

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, text-to-speech

Below is my code for one of the waterfall steps in webchat code in Nodejs. I am able to enable voice option in webchat but while it converts from text to speech it is not able to recognize prompts, though it is able to recognise simple text. Please help me in enabling speech option for prompts as well.

Also added code for html file where speech option is enabled.

Solution needed : In text to speech it should be able to recognize prompts also, currently it is able to recognise the text messages.

```
async financeFirstStep(step) {
    console.log("Inside financeFirstStep::");
    return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: 'Please select a option to which your query is related to-',
        size:'Medium',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(['Account Statement', 'Credit Limit','Credit Term','Status of Claim','Home']),
        style: ListStyle.heroCard,
        retryPrompt: 'Invalid value entered. \r\nPlease select from the available options-'
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #webchat {
      height: 75%;
      width: 75%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
  <script src="https://aka.ms/csspeech/jsbrowserpackageraw"></script>

  <script>
    const styleOptions = {
      botAvatarImage: 'https://i.ibb.co/HVzy48h/Stu.png',
      userAvatarImage: 'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64',
      bubbleBackground: 'rgb(240,248,255)',
      bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgb(30,144,255)'
    };


    (async function() {

      // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
      const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({
        dispatch
      }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
          dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
              name: 'webchat/join',
              value: {
                language: window.navigator.language
              }
            }
          });
        }
        return next(action);
      });

      // Create directline Object
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        // Secret is permanent while token is only valid per conversation
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
          secret: 'SECRET',
          watermark: 10
        }),
        //directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
        userID: "USERID",
        styleOptions,
        store,
        webSpeechPonyfillFactory: await createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
          credentials: {
            region: 'eastus',
            subscriptionKey: 'subscriptionKey'
          }
        })
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
      document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    })().catch(err => console.error(err));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To enable prompts in text to speech could you please refer this links 
 [To create prompts to gather user input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript-) , [Prompt for user input in  v3 JavaScript  |MS DOC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) & [Using Dialogs and Prompts to build a conversational BOT on Azure](https://thewebspark.com/2017/12/30/using-dialogs-and-prompts-to-build-a-conversational-bot-on-azure/)

Comment: These documents list the steps to add prompts in BOT not how to enable speech option for them. For my Webchat BOT Prompts are enabled already, and while converting from speech to text it ignores prompts while it reads other texts.

Comment: Could you please look into this tutorial https://github.com/DelphiABall/Azure-Cognitive-Services